What are the words that mean to make something (look) smaller?
There are plenty of words that means to make something (look) bigger, but I can't find their exact antonyms.

magnify - make something look bigger
enlarge - make something bigger
zoom in - move the zoom lens to make the photograph bigger
amplify - make the sound stronger, increase the volume

What are their exact antonyms?

?-fy (minify?) - make something look smaller
en-? (ensmall?) - make something smaller
zoom out - move the zoom lens to make the photograph smaller
?-fy (?) - make the sound weaker, decrease the volume

The expression "zoom out" is the only one that is the exact antonym of "zoom in", but what about the other three words? Do there exist exact antonyms?

Not all English words have direct antonyms. I cannot think of an antonym for the word magnify directly. You were pretty close with the antonym for enlarge being "ensmall". There is actually the word "ensmallen" it's not a very common word but is the antonym for the word "embiggen" which is as well uncommon but is a synonym for the word enlarge. I would also say the closest direct antonym for "amplify" would be "attenuate" this particularly concerns physics when talking about sound waves.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

We use a convex lens (a.k.a. magnifying glass) to magnify a picture, while we use a concave lens (a.k.a. _____fying glass) to ____ a picture.
